# Weird second file when opening any LaTeX file with TeXShop

Tags: texshop

Suddenly TeXShop shows the strange behaviour that it opens a second untitled file (always the same) whenever I open any LaTeX file. I cannot edit that second file. I don't know how it came about and I can't get rid of it. Also a file named untitled does not exist. Any hints how to remove that? I am running Ventura 13.3.1 and TeXShop Version 4.44.

Comment: You might try deleting TeXShop and reinstalling it.